# ¿Cómo acceder a la bandeja SMS Android?

Tags: java, android, gps

Estoy realizando una aplicación de rastreo en donde mando un **SMS** y recibo el link de Google Maps de donde esta situado el GPS, mi pregunta es ¿Cómo hacer que la aplicación intercepte el SMS recibido y coja el link de Google Maps?

Gracias y saludos

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada, deberás añadir el siguiente permiso a tu aplicación:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
```

Posteriormente, para leer los diferentes mensajes puedes usar el siguiente código:

```
public static final String INBOX = "content://sms/inbox"; //<- Bandeja de entrada
// public static final String SENT = "content://sms/sent"; <- Enviados
// public static final String DRAFT = "content://sms/draft"; <- Borradores
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse(INBOX), null, null, null, null);
String enlace = "";

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) { 
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
       String cuerpo = cursor.getString(c.getColumnIndex("body"));
       //Puedes poner algo que sepas que siempre va a contener el enlace 
       //a Google Maps (Yo he puesto 'maps' como ejemplo)
       if (cuerpo.contains("maps")) { 
            enlace = cuerpo;
       }
    }
} else {
   //No hay SMS
}
```

*Nota*: Hago el uso del `contains` para comprobar si el mensaje contiene un texto que parezca ser un enlace a Google Maps (Esto funcionará así si el mensaje solo contiene un enlace, sino tendrías que hacer uso del `substring` o lo que más te convenga para coger sólo el enlace del texto).

Comment: Donde pones cursor1 y c.getString no iria cursor.moveToNext() y cursor.getString? Gracias!!!

Comment: @Miquel Si, problemas de hacer copia y pega :D Gracias, ya está corregido

Comment: crees que puede existir algun problema al utilizarlo en un android 6.0 porque lo he probado y me crashea, el codigo este lo he puesto en un boton para que al pulsarlo lo busque.